# Returning Variables back into a template

Tags: theme-development, functions, themes, templates, page-template

If I put a function that I want to use in a template I can put it into functions.php

```
function myfunction(){
echo 'My String';
}
```

`add_action('myfunction','myfunction');`

and in a template file put:

```
do_action('myfunction');
```

This appears to only work if writing something out to the screen. If I wanted to return a variable instead to the page. E.g.

```
function myfunction(){
return 'My String';
}

$string = do_action('myfunction');
```

and capture it instead of print it. How would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's filters for that.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'template_filter', 'wpse_102706_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function wpse_102706_filter_callback( $defaults, $case )
{
    $args = wp_parse_args( array(
        'some_key' => 'some_modified_value'
    ), $defaults );

    return $args
}
```

Then in your template just add in the defaults:

```
apply_filters( 'template_filter', array( 'some_key' => 'default_val' ), 'single' );
```

More info in Codex about the [Plugins API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).