# Pass variable from action back to template

Tags: functions, templates

I'm new to developing with WordPress. I read [here](https://tommcfarlin.com/sending-data-post/) that a good way to process data posted from forms is to insert an action on the init function like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'contact_form_send_email' );
```

My function seems to be processing the data correctly, but I can't figure out how to make a variable available within the same template that has the form.

What is the way to do this? I've heard that setting global variables is not a good way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning Variables back into a template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102706/returning-variables-back-into-a-template)

Comment: Try this one too. Seems cleaner. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50016/120646

Comment: I can't get the second of these to work, it say undefined variable in template file. I must have done something else wrong.

Comment: @Saas3 This is a duplicate, but of this un-answered question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259800/set-query-var-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-init-hook - seems that you can't use init with set_query_vars

Comment: What about directly manipulating $_POST as noted in the link you posted? It's clearly looks hacky, but if it works, it's something.

Comment: Yes thanks that did solve the problem, it just doesn't seem like the WP way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `add_action()` and `add_filter()` is semantic not technical, except that a filter expects a returned value and an action does/will not.
The question is whether `contact_form_send_email()` **needs** to be called-at /hooked-to `init`.

If not, you can define your filter in the template with `apply_filters()`, and then hook to it to run your function and return a value to it.

In *template page*:

```
$some_variable = 'some value';
$some_variable = apply_filters('my_filter_hook', $some_variable);
```

In *functions.php*

```
add_filter('my_filter_hook', 'contact_form_send_email', 10, 1 );

function contact_form_send_email( $some_variable ) {
    //do stuff
    $some_variable = 'some new value';

    return $some_variable;

}
```

---

To help determine where you need to hook, this [Actions Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) can be useful. Scroll down and you will see some template specific hooks as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems like what I was looking for, let me come back to this once I've had a chance to digest. Cheers

Comment: This is what I was looking for and you're right that I didn't need to hook into init. I'm still a little confused by the second argument of apply_filters, my function is picking up the $_POST array and I don't want to send anything, so I just inserted a 1 in this argument. It works, but still feels a bit un-natural. Do you have any suggestions? I can post full code somewhere if need be, perhaps on a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting feature in the WordPress that you might find it useful in situations like this. It's the ability to add something into the cache and retrieve it later.

Since you are hooking into the init, you can retrieve your cache afterward. This is done by using the `wp_cache_add()` function:

```
wp_cache_add( $key, $data, $group, $expire );
```

Add whatever data you wish, and then fetch them on your template:

```
wp_cache_get( $key, $group );
```

You can also delete the cache afterward if you wish. Take a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) codex page.